# Helm chart stuck in PodInitializing state indefinitely

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

I'm running a [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) cluster on an Ubuntu server at home, and I have it connected to a local NAS server for persistent storage. I've been using it as my personal proving grounds for learning Kubernetes, but I seem to encounter problem after problem at just about every step of the way.

I've got the [NFS Client Provisioner](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-client-provisioner) Helm chart installed which I've confirmed works - it will dynamically provision PVCs on my NAS server. I later was able to successfully install the [Postgres](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) Helm chart, or so I thought. After creating it I was able to connect to it using a SQL client, and I was feeling good.

Until a couple of days later, I noticed the pod was showing 0/1 containers ready. Although interestingly, the nfs-client-provisioner pod was still showing 1/1. Long story short: I've deleted/purged the Postgres Helm chart, and attempted to reinstall it, but now it no longer works. In fact, nothing new that I try to deploy works. Everything looks as though it's going to work, but then just hangs on either Init or ContainerCreating forever.

With Postgres in particular, the command I've been running is this:

```
helm install --name postgres stable/postgresql -f postgres.yaml
```

And my `postgres.yaml` file looks like this:

```
persistence:
    storageClass: nfs-client
    accessMode: ReadWriteMany
    size: 2Gi
```

But if I do a `kubectl get pods` I see still see this:

```
NAME                    READY  STATUS    RESTARTS  AGE
nfs-client-provisioner  1/1    Running   1         11d
postgres-postgresql-0   0/1    Init:0/1  0         3h51m
```

If I do a `kubectl describe pod postgres-postgresql-0`, this is the output:

```
Name:               postgres-postgresql-0
Namespace:          default
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               stjohn/192.168.1.217
Start Time:         Thu, 28 Mar 2019 12:51:02 -0500
Labels:             app=postgresql
                chart=postgresql-3.11.7
                controller-revision-hash=postgres-postgresql-5bfb9cc56d
                heritage=Tiller
                release=postgres
                role=master
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=postgres-postgresql-0
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Pending
IP:                 
Controlled By:      StatefulSet/postgres-postgresql
Init Containers:
  init-chmod-data:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest
    Image ID:      
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami
      if [ -d /bitnami/postgresql/data ]; then
    chmod  0700 /bitnami/postgresql/data;
      fi

    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:        250m
      memory:     256Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/postgresql from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-h4gph (ro)
Containers:
  postgres-postgresql:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0
    Image ID:       
    Port:           5432/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      250m
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   exec [sh -c exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h localhost] delay=30s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Readiness:  exec [sh -c exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h localhost] delay=5s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=6
    Environment:
      PGDATA:             /bitnami/postgresql
      POSTGRES_USER:      postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'postgresql-password' in secret 'postgres-postgresql'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /bitnami/postgresql from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-h4gph (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-postgres-postgresql-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-h4gph:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-h4gph
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

And if I do a `kubectl get pod postgres-postgresql-0 -o yaml`, this is the output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-03-28T17:51:02Z"
  generateName: postgres-postgresql-
  labels:
    app: postgresql
    chart: postgresql-3.11.7
    controller-revision-hash: postgres-postgresql-5bfb9cc56d
    heritage: Tiller
    release: postgres
    role: master
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: postgres-postgresql-0
  name: postgres-postgresql-0
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: StatefulSet
    name: postgres-postgresql
    uid: 0d3ef673-5182-11e9-bf14-b8975a0ca30c
  resourceVersion: "1953329"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/postgres-postgresql-0
  uid: 0d4dfb56-5182-11e9-bf14-b8975a0ca30c
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: PGDATA
      value: /bitnami/postgresql
    - name: POSTGRES_USER
      value: postgres
    - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: postgresql-password
      name: postgres-postgresql
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h localhost
      failureThreshold: 6
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    name: postgres-postgresql
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5432
      name: postgresql
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - exec pg_isready -U "postgres" -h localhost
      failureThreshold: 6
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    resources:
      requests:
    cpu: 250m
    memory: 256Mi
    securityContext:
      procMount: Default
      runAsUser: 1001
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
      name: data
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-h4gph
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  hostname: postgres-postgresql-0
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      chown -R 1001:1001 /bitnami
      if [ -d /bitnami/postgresql/data ]; then
    chmod  0700 /bitnami/postgresql/data;
      fi
    image: docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: init-chmod-data
    resources:
      requests:
    cpu: 250m
    memory: 256Mi
    securityContext:
      procMount: Default
      runAsUser: 0
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /bitnami/postgresql
      name: data
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-h4gph
      readOnly: true
  nodeName: stjohn
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1001
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  subdomain: postgres-postgresql-headless
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: data-postgres-postgresql-0
  - name: default-token-h4gph
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-h4gph
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-03-28T17:51:02Z"
    message: 'containers with incomplete status: [init-chmod-data]'
    reason: ContainersNotInitialized
    status: "False"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-03-28T17:51:02Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [postgres-postgresql]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-03-28T17:51:02Z"
    message: 'containers with unready status: [postgres-postgresql]'
    reason: ContainersNotReady
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2019-03-28T17:51:02Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:10.7.0
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: postgres-postgresql
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      waiting:
    reason: PodInitializing
  hostIP: 192.168.1.217
  initContainerStatuses:
  - image: docker.io/bitnami/minideb:latest
    imageID: ""
    lastState: {}
    name: init-chmod-data
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    state:
      waiting:
    reason: PodInitializing
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: "2019-03-28T17:51:02Z"
```

I don't see anything obvious in these to be able to pinpoint what might be going on. And I've already rebooted the server just to see if that might help. Any thoughts? Why won't my containers start?

Comment: Have you looked at logs (errors essentially)?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your **initContainer** is stuck in the *PodInitializing* state. The most likely scenario is that your PVCs are not ready. I recommend you `describe` your `data-postgres-postgresql-0` PVC to make sure that the volume has actually been provisioned and is in the `READY` state. Your NFS provisioner may be working, but that specific PV/PVC may not have been created due to an error. I have run into similar phenomena with the EFS provisioner with AWS.

Comment: Running that describe command reveals the PVC is in the `Bound` state. Can you shed any light on what that might mean?

Comment: Any other events on the PVC? If it's bound, then it should be working correctly. I will need some more information to help debug.

Comment: I am totally stumped. It seems my cluster is in a state where I can't launch *any* new pods, full stop. They all get stuck in PodInitializing. Even trying to run this incredibly simple command gets stuck: `kubectl run --restart=Never alpine --image=alpine --command -- tail -f /dev/null`. That one doesn't have any PVCs at all! Running `kubectl get events --all-namespaces=true` doesn't show anything out of the ordinary, running a `kubectl describe pod/alpine` doesn't show any problems, and even watching all the log messages with [kail](https://github.com/boz/kail) doesn't reveal anything either.

Comment: I think I will simply have to re-image the machine this cluster is running on and start from scratch. I just hope it doesn't eventually get back into this same state!

Comment: Did you check the reason for the `PodInitializing` state? You can find some logs with `kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp` and figure out why exactly your pods are not getting scheduled. If you are using `cluster-autoscaler`, you can also follow the pod logs to see if there's anything blocking the pod state transition!

Comment: Yes I did; as I mentioned I've tried `kubectl get events` before. With just trying to spin up an Alpine container, the only two events that appear are `Scheduled` and then `Pulling`. After that it just sits there. I am not using a cluster-autoscaler. Again, this is a microk8s installation.

Comment: Interesting... I think your approach to restart your node is probably the best approach now. Docker pulling images and getting stuck seems to be a common issue and there are many GitHub issues opened for it. After a preliminary search, most of the solutions involve killing the container engine and restarting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the event command of kubectl. This will give you the event for your pod.

To filter for a specific pod you can use a field-selector:

kubectl get event --namespace abc-namespace --field-selector involvedObject.name=my-pod-zl6m6